# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Islam breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  7         11
Users destroyed                                  83          0
Users deleted                                    32          0
Users contacted                                  15          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           214        315
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               42         77
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        132        431
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              156        432
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               542      1,445
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              621      1,284
Tags merged                                       1          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             2          1
Tag synonyms created                              1          0
Questions reopened                               11          0
Questions protected                              10        108
Questions migrated                                3          0
Questions flagged⁴                               22        356
Questions closed                                996        112
Question flags handled⁴                         270        108
Posts unlocked                                    1          2
Posts undeleted                                  11         49
Posts locked                                      1        217
Posts deleted⁵                                  836      1,916
Posts bumped                                      0      1,833
Escalations to the CM team                        3          0
Comments undeleted                               32          0
Comments flagged                                168        397
Comments deleted⁶                             1,642        887
Comment flags handled                           289        276
Answers flagged                                 465      1,402
Answer flags handled                          1,508        359
All comments on a post moved to chat              4          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...